# Installation script needs to be run as a certain (regular) user but needs to create a system directory

Tags: software-installation, sudo

I'm new to Linux, let me explain the issue. I'm trying to install `comsol` with some sort of network license.

If I use `sudo ./setup` the server directory does not recognize the username "root". The server recognizes my username which is zahir. If I just write `./setup` the installation passes the license check stage but can't proceed since it cannot create directory in `/usr/local`.

What command should I use so that the installation runs as `zahir` but with root privileges?

Comment: You can try `sudo su` and install it as root. That way environment variables like USER are changed to root.

Comment: WHat exactly are you trying to install? Is it something from [here](http://www.comsol.com/)? Could you show us this "setup" script? You may simply need to edit it to change the expected username.

Comment: yes Comsol multiphysics. trying to install using sudo su is a problem. Since the installation is expecting user "zahir" to install not the user "root".

there is a setup file which is a platform independent setup. 

I guess the question boils down to is there way to run the setup as "zahir" but with root permission? can I change "zahir" as a root user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try looking for any help for the `setup` script. Maybe it came with a `README` file or it accepts a `-h` switch (check by running `./setup -h`). A reasonably well-written script should allow you to change the installation directory. You can do something like

```
./setup --prefix=/home/zahir/
```

or similar (depending on what you find out from the script's help).

This will install `comsol` in your home directory which you can then move to `/usr/local` using `sudo`.

**Update**

You reported that the above method worked but the `comsol` command is not recognized. This simply means you need to add the location of the `comsol` binary to your `PATH` variable.

Let's assume that `comsol` was installed in `/usr/local/comsol35`, you simply need to add `/usr/local/comsol35/bin` to your `PATH` variable. (The actual path on your system may vary).

**To add a path to your `PATH`** variable:

Simply run the following:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/comsol35/bin
```

This will change the `PATH` in your current session only. To make the change permanent, you can do:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/comsol35/bin' >> ~/.bashrc
```

It's very important to use single quotes rather than double-quotes for the above command so that `$PATH` is added literally to your `.bashrc` and not interpolated. You should also make sure you use `>>` instead of `>` in order not to destroy the contents of your `.bashrc`.

After you run the `echo` command, the `comsol` command should be available from any new terminal you open. If you want to make the change take effect within the terminal you used to issue the `echo` command, you have to run

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

(yes the command is only a period)

Comment: thanks. I could do that. The problem is after installation the command "comsol" is not recognized which according to thier documentaiton should be the command to start the program. Infact I am trying to run it with matlab. By installing it this way without the elevated privilage none of the default commands work. That means I am in eternal work around :(. Any other idea?

Comment: @user1188038 Answer updated. See if this helps.

Comment: @user1188038 IIRC, `comsol` may also require some Java packages to start correctly.

Comment: but I have problem while trying to run it with matlab. typically one writes comsol server matlab and it starts.

Comment: instead of the command I can do manual connection. Thanks very much.... I guess I will have to live with it for now. I am not sure why this is the case :(. It worked like a charm in windows. I just moved to linux last week :(

Comment: @user1188038 If this answer solves your question, please consider accepting it. Meanwhile, I'd be happy to follow up with you about the `matlab` issue in chat. Reply here if you're interested and I'll set up a chat room.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was all fine yesterday. After restart, now I get Java error and comsol crashes out. I guess your hunch was right :)

Comment: # A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f3b40e4d3e6, pid=4435, tid=139896219707200
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libcsgraphics_scene_common.so+0x1e13e6]  _ZN12flgraphics3d12SceneManager14deactivateFromERKSs+0x26

Current thread (0x0000000001b21000):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=4435, stack(0x00007fff03548000,0x00007fff03748000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000098

Comment: @user1188038 That's really strange. If my hunch were right, it wouldn't have started in the first place. Did you perhaps change the user you're starting it with? How about (re)installing the JRE (Java runtime environment)?

Answer (score 0):

There are some commands that can't be run via `sudo` such as apparently your`sudo ./setup`. I usually become root in the shell as follows:

*option 1* - may not be supported on your system

```
$ sudo -i
```

*option 2* - should be widely support

```
$ sudo su -
```

Once you've run one of these 2 commands you're effectively root in that shell and can run your `./setup` command. Make sure you change directories (`cd`) back to where your `./setup` program was being run from.

#### Run as root & zahir?

If you need to run the installation as yourself, `zahir`, you can make the directories that are necessary to do the installation, so that `zahir` can install into them ahead of time, and then run the `./setup` as `zahir`.

```
$ sudo mkdir -p /usr/local
$ sudo chown -R zahir /usr/local
```

Comment: The OP's problem is that the `setup` script is actually expecting the user installing it to be called `zahir` while it needs root privileges (or at least the ability to create a directory in `/usr/local`).

Comment: @JosephR. - thanks for pointing that out. Hmm...

Comment: Thank you Joseph for clearing it. That is indeed the problem.

Comment: Re your update: That would be @Ein5t3in 's suggestion

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah I didn't see his suggestion, focusing only on my window. His didn't mention how, just that you could do it. Given the OP is new to Linux, mine shows how to do the actual commands.

Answer (score 0):

Mu guess is that the `setup` script is reading the username from your environment. It probably checks one of the `$USER` or `$USERNAME` environment variables (these are default vars, you can check their value by running `echo $USER` in your terminal). It probably contains a line like

```
current_user=$USERNAME
```

Try searching the file for `$USER`:

```
grep USER setup
```

You should then be able to change it to `zahir`, something like:

```
current_user=zahir
```

If you could post the script somewhere, I would be happy to have a look and give you a more specific answer.

Comment: the setup file is an exe. so I am afraid that I am not sure where to find the script.

Comment: @user1188038 what do you mean an exe? What is the output of `file setup`? It should just be an executable script, in other words, text.